# Edit state titles when creating a US map with Google Maps API

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, overlay

Is it possible to edit or add to the two-letter state indicator when [creating a US Map](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/8/9/Centering-a-Google-Map-on-America) with Google Maps API v3?

I'd like to include statistics for each state in the abbreviation tag (such as a count of cases, users, ect).

So instead of just showing `NY`, I would display `NY - 2,345`.

[image]

Comment: You would need to create a styled map that removes those labels and add your own labels in the appropriate locations.

Comment: I guess that would be `"featureType": "administrative.province"` and `"elementType": "labels.text"` for which you would set `"visibility": "off"`. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyle